# Using LINQ to group and sum

Tags: c#, linq

So i have a List called transactions.

```
var itemA = new TransactionItem() { ProductId = 1, Quantity = 2 };
var itemB = new TransactionItem() { ProductId = 1, Quantity = 3 };

var tranA = new Transaction() { Type = TransactionType.credit, Items = new List<TransactionItem>() { itemA } };
var tranB = new Transaction() { Type = TransactionType.credit, Items = new List<TransactionItem>() { itemB } };

var tranC = new Transaction() { Type = TransactionType.debit, Items = new List<TransactionItem>() { itemA } };
var transactions = new List<Transaction>() { tranA, tranB };
```

How do I get a grouping that cancels out Credits and Debits; ie in the above I have two credits where ProductID equals 1, totaling 5, and one debit where ProductID equals 1, totaling 2, so I'd like to project a new list of transactionItems showing the resulting positive amount.

(background: I'm trying to create a function that takes a list of transactions and determines after all the credits and debits what items a person should have remaining on account.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem

```
transactions.SelectMany(t => t.Items, (t, ti) => new { t.Type, ti.ProductId, ti.Quantity })
            .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId, x => x.Type == TransactionType.credit ? x.Quantity : -x.Quantity)
            .Select(x => new TransactionItem
            {
                ProductId = x.Key,
                Quantity = x.Sum()
            })
```

The result is

> Collection containing one TransactionItem with values: { ProductId=1, Quantity=3 }

Some improvement

If you can change the TransactionType to be this

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    credit = 1,
    debit = -1
}
```

Then the LINQ query could be simplified to that

```
transactions.SelectMany(t => t.Items, (t, ti) => new { t.Type, ti.ProductId, ti.Quantity })
            .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId, x => (int)x.Type * x.Quantity)
            .Select(x => new TransactionItem
            {
                ProductId = x.Key,
                Quantity = x.Sum()
            })
```

Comment: @EvanMorrison any feedback?

Comment: Yeah, I had just fixed up some of my code and tweaked ChaseMedallion's answer to work, but yours works perfectly. I had some transactions with null Items. Thanks.

Comment: @EvanMorrison nice, if you have any other question I would love to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "cancel out credits and debits", but it sounds like maybe you want to subtract one from the other?

```
// first, use SelectMany() to flatten the "list of lists" structure
var result = transaction.SelectMany(
        // for each transaction, select all items
        t => t.Items,
        // for each (transaction, item) pair, select out
        // an anonymous type with product id and quantity (I'm using Type
        // here to give Quantity a sign, although I'm not sure that's
        // what you meant)
        (t, ti) => new 
        { 
            ti.ProductId, 
            t.Type == TransactionType.credit ? ti.Quantity : -ti.Quantity 
        }
    )
    // take the big list and group up by product id
    .GroupBy(t => t.ProductId)
    // for each group, aggregate a new item with the sum quantity
    .Select(g => new TransactionItem { ProductId = g.Key, Quantity = g.Sum() })
    // remove items where everything canceled out
    .Where(t => t.Quantity != 0)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: line 12: t.Type == TransactionType will want a Type instead of quantity... I'm still piecing through it all though..